# "fieldType": "Sig" with fully qualified name not prefixing with "signature" creates java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, apache, pdfbox

I am getting this exception when I give fully qualified names as some random names such as "**test**" for `"fieldType": "Sig"` using **Apache PDFBox** with version **2.0.13** as it  is latest version of it, but when I give fully qualified name *prefixed with "**signature**" it is working fine*. Please let me know what may be the root cause for this issue.

> org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSString cannot be cast to org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary

The stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSString cannot be cast to org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDSignatureField.getValue(PDSignatureField.java:170)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDSignatureField.getSignature(PDSignatureField.java:116)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.findSignatureField(PDDocument.java:460)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.addSignature(PDDocument.java:365)
```

The code:

```
private PDSignature findExistingSignature(PDAcroForm pdAcroForm, String signatureFieldName) {
    PDSignature signature = null;
    if (pdAcroForm != null) {
        PDSignatureField signatureField = (PDSignatureField) pdAcroForm.getField(signatureFieldName);
        System.out.println("signatureField >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>."+ signatureField);  // !!!!!!!!!
        if (null != signatureField) {
            signature = signatureField.getSignature();  // !!!!!!!!!
            if (signature == null) {
                signature = new PDSignature();
                signatureField.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.V, signature);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("The signature field received ::" + signatureFieldName + " is already signed.");
            }
        }
    }
    return signature;
}
```

This is what printed

> signatureField >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.Vimal{type: PDSignatureField value: COSString{}}

Please use empty signature fields in any pdf so that the
signature field does not have a signature dictionary in its /V element, but a string for testing as iam unable to attach sample PDF.

Comment: please add some code and share your PDF if possible. The exception comes if a signature field does not have a signature dictionary in its /V element, but a string. Could it be you somehow "reused" a non signature field? I'll fix the ClassCastException tonight (for some reason this is a bug in 2.0, but not in the trunk), but then PDSignature.getValue() would simply return null, and you'll have a different problem.

Comment: Added my findExistingSignature method and i did sysout of that field you mentioned for reference

Comment: *"Please use empty signature fields in any pdf so that the signature field does not have a signature dictionary in its /V element"* - If the value of **V** in the signature field is not set, the `PDField.toString` method looks for an inherited value elsewhere. So apparently some parent field has a string **V** value. Or there is a **V** entry in the **AcroForm** dictionary - for some weird reason PDFBox, when looking for inherited values, even looks there...

Comment: The ClassCastException should be gone now, use the latest jar here: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.14-SNAPSHOT/  I suspect that your signature has an empty string in /V. What you could do is to show what is in `signatureField.getCOSObject().getItem(COSName.V)`. There should be nothing or a dictionary. Anyway. with the new code the string would be ignored.

Comment: What code did you have to start, i.e. did you use one of the examples from the source code download? Did these work immediately? Or are they just failing with a specific PDF? Can you work with a PDF created by the CreateEmptySignatureForm.java example?

Comment: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-app:jar:2.0.14-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-app:jar:2.0.14-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-parent:pom:2.0.14-20190221.183643-162 in http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of apache.snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced.

Comment: mvn install thows this error when i added below dependency in my pom.xml<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
   <artifactId>pdfbox-app</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.14-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: I'm not that deep into maven to be able to help; another solution would be to build yourself locally ( https://pdfbox.apache.org/building.html ),  a third one would be to take that signature and then `signatureField.getCOSObject().removeItem(COSName.V)` to remove the incorrect assignment.